# UseState to set true or false from a parent component

Tags: reactjs

I've got a parent component, thant send a value that return true or false to his child

```
//Parent
const disableButton = reservationsSchedule && reservationsSchedule.includes(schedule.id)
return  <ScheduleLine disableButton={disableButton}  />
```

Then, in his child, I want to setDisabled to true of false depending on disableButton
I try many things, like :

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(disableButton)
    console.log(disableButton, "disableButton1")

    useEffect(() => {
     
        console.log(disableButton && disableButton, "disableButton2")
        setDisabled(disableButton)
      
    }, [])
```

But it doesn't work. The first console.log of disableButton1 get me true of false but didn't setDisabled to true. And the second console.log of disableButton2 is always null.

Should I use useEffect in this case ? More condition ?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code for child? Also do you want the child to be able to set the disabled property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your prop (disableButton) in useEffect. So, it runs every time prop is updated.

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(disableButton)
console.log(disableButton, "disableButton1")

useEffect(() => {
 
    console.log(disableButton && disableButton, "disableButton2")
    setDisabled(disableButton)
  
}, [disableButton])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your child you need to add disableButton inside the second parameter to useEffect as a dependency, which will tell useEffect that whenever disableButton value changes run useEffect.

empty array means that it will only run on mounting, not whenever any update happens.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(disableButton && disableButton, "disableButton2")
  setDisabled(disableButton)  
}, [disableButton])
```